# I want to set a background color behind my progress bar that won't grin all the time

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, frontend, styles

I have an animated progress bar, the normal one in example 1.  But the one I want will be like in example 2, but the one in the back will play non-stop.

example 1
[image]

example 2
[image]

```css
.progress {
    display: flex;
    height: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: .5625rem;
    background-color: #e4e7ea;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.progress-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #348fe2;
    transition: width .6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress h-5px rounded-pill bg-white bg-opacity-10">
  <div class="progress-bar" data-animation="width" data-value="11.6%" style="animation: 1s linear 1s infinite normal none running progress-bar-stripes;width: 61.6%;background: linear-gradient(40deg, #ffffff, #000000 50%, #ffffff);"></div>
</div>
```

I tried putting a background, but I'm having problems with the animation.

Comment: Can we get the associated HTML please ?

Comment: https://seantheme.com/color-admin/admin/html/ui_general.html is here

Comment: @Alexis sir, I want it to look like such a light is playing inside my progress bar

Answer (score 0):

The default css for the animation is:

```css
.progress-bar-striped {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 
    25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 
    50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
}
```

You can mess with that to change the animation itself.

Or / and you can just change the background color:

```css
.bg-indigo {
    background-color: black;
}
```

In both cases you have to overwrite the exsisting css.